# PDO pgsql is disabled

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-4

This is so confusing. I already commented out the extension for `PDO pgsql` however PHP won't load it.

[image]

Restarted the server after that but still no `pgsql` value on PDO. It only sees the `MySQL` driver. I also check if the DLL is present in the extension directory, and yes it is. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this article http://blog.lysender.com/2010/08/php-and-postgresql-on-windows/

Comment: Maybe it is because the .ini file you are modifying is not the one read by the server. Have a look at the top of your phpinfo page to see which one is the good one.